# display images from multi directories

Tags: php

I want to display images from multi derctories.

I have this main folder ( backgrounds ) and inside this DIR I have 45 folders each folder have between 10-20 images.

I want to display all the images from the directories.

regards
Al3in

Comment: Will there be any images within this `backgrounds` top-level directory that you **won't** want displaying?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead:

```
<?php
// Recursivly search through a directory and sub-directories for all
// image files. The returned result will be an array will all matches
// and their path (relative to the path sent in through the $dir argument)
//
// $dir       - Directory to search through
// $filetypes - Array of file extensions to match
// 
// Returns: Array() of files that match the $filetypes filter (or standard
//          image file extensions by default).
//
function recursiveFileSearch($dir = '.', $filetypes = null)
{
  if (!is_dir($dir))
    return Array();

  // create a regex filter so we only grab image files
  if (is_null($filetypes))
    $filetypes = Array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
  $fileFilter = '/\.('.implode('|',$filetypes).')$/i';

  // build a results array
  $images = Array();

  // open the directory and begin searching
  if (($dHandle = opendir($dir)) !== false)
  {
    // iterate all files
    while (($file = readdir($dHandle)) !== false)
    {
      // we don't want the . or .. directory aliases
      if ($file == '.' || $file == '..')
        continue;

      // compile the path for reference
      $path = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;

      // is it a directory? if so, append the results
      if (is_dir($path))
        $results = array_merge($results, recursiveFileSearch($path,$filetypes));
      // must be a file, see if it matches our patter and add it if necessary
      else if (is_file($path) && preg_match($fileFilter,$file))
        $results[] = str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,'/',$path);
    }

    // close the directory when we're through
    closedir($dHandle);
  }

  // return the outcome
  return $results;
}
?>
<html><body><?php array_map(create_function('$i','echo "<img src=\"{$i}\" alt=\"{$i}\" /><br />";'),recursiveFileSearch('backgrounds')); ?></body></html>
```